# Terraform parallel VM creation

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to do a very basic task on Terraform v0.10.7.

I have up to 100 VM to be povisionned using terraform + vSphere provisionner and I want to be able to launch several resource creations in the same time and not one after the other. For the moment the second VM is created only if the previous one is finished.

I've tried to read the doc but I didn't found any answer, could somebody help me ?

```
variable "user" {}
variable "password" {}
variable "vsphere_server" {}


provider "vsphere" {

 user           = "${var.user}"

 password       = "${var.password}"

 vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"

 allow_unverified_ssl = "true"

}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "dum03" {
  name          = "dum03"
  hostname      = "dumHN"
  folder        = "Ansible VM"
  vcpu          = 2
  memory        = 4096
  domain        = "MYDOMAIN"
  datacenter    = "myDatacenter"
  cluster       = "NET-TEST"

  network_interface {
    label              = "NET-TEST"
    ipv4_address       = "10.20.30.40"
    ipv4_prefix_length = "24"
    ipv4_gateway       = "10.20.30.254"
  }
  disk {
    datastore = "datastore"
    template  = "mytemplate"
  }
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "dum04" {
  name          = "dum4"
  hostname      = "dumHN2"
  folder        = "Ansible VM"
  vcpu          = 2
  memory        = 4096
  domain        = "MYDOMAIN"
  datacenter    = "myDatacenter"
  cluster       = "test"

  network_interface {
    label              = "NET-TEST"
    ipv4_address       = "15.25.35.45"
    ipv4_prefix_length = "24"
    ipv4_gateway       = "10.20.30.254"
  }
  disk {
    datastore = "mydatastore"
    template  = "mytemplate"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution :

I generate my terraform files using Ansible.

A new directory is created for each machine and I generate my scripts in each directoy for ONE and only ONE machine.

Finally, still using Ansible, I command an asynchronous "terraform apply -var-file=XXX.tvars" for each scripts locations with a with_items for each location/each machine and register this command.

The VMs are all triggered in the same time.

By registering my command earlier, I have now access to a job_id, so now I can control the result after.

```
- name: Apply ressource creation
  command: "terraform apply -var-file=./{{environment_name}}.tfvars 
-var-file=./instance.tfvars"
 args:
    chdir: /appli/terraform/{{item.name}}/
 async: 3600
 poll: 0
 with_items: "{{VM_provide}}"
 ignore_errors: yes
 register: creation


- name: Wait for the creation job to complete
  async_status: jid="{{creation_item.ansible_job_id}}"
  with_items: "{{creation.results}}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "creation_item"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 200
  poll: 10
```

Comment: Except now you have multiple `terraform.state` files instead of one for your whole deployment which means it's now harder to manage. Also, any sane VMware deployment will limit how many operations a user is allowed to issue concurrently to the cluster so I'd never expect you to be able to create 100 VM's all at once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to start all your VMs within one `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource using `count` statement. Count starts from 0.

It should be like:

```
variable "vm_count" = 2

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "dum" {
  name          = "dum${format("%02d", count.index+3)}"
  hostname      = "dumHN${count.index+1}"
  count         = "${var.vm_count}"
  folder        = "Ansible VM"
  vcpu          = 2
  memory        = 4096
  domain        = "MYDOMAIN"
  datacenter    = "myDatacenter"
  cluster       = "NET-TEST"

  network_interface {
    label              = "NET-TEST"
    ipv4_address       = "10.20.30.${40 + count.index * 5)}"
    ipv4_prefix_length = "24"
    ipv4_gateway       = "10.20.30.254"
  }
  disk {
    datastore = "datastore"
    template  = "mytemplate"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry but I didn't solved the problem like.

Actually my problem was that the ressources were created one after the other which was so long, but defining my resources themself wasn't a problem.

Please check the following answer to get my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Some providers (AWS, for example), handle API rate limiting issues at a lower level by implementing graceful backoff/retry in their respective API clients. For this reason, Terraform does not use this parallelism feature to address API rate limits directly.

[Check the official doc of terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/graph.html#walking-the-graph)

Answer (score 0):

I try this and works:

In this example I deploy 3 vms in the same file with different resources like hostname.

Change the variable resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm(number)" for the number of vms to deploy:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm"
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm1"
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm2"
```

Here the link with full config:
[terraformconfig](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Apsl9ddu8BDYgscvEWtmhjqlDCSI2A)

Comment: please fix formatting